# Tiger VNC Configuration Help (Ubuntu Server 20.04, Ubuntu Desktop DE)

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, remote, aws

I'm trying to configure Tiger VNC on Ubuntu Server 20.04 via PuTTY. I installed Ubuntu Desktop to use as my desktop environment, but am unsure how to configure the VNC specifically using this DE. Any help would be greatly appreciated!